# Pulling Data From JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I have a simple JSON string that looks like

```
(
    {
    ID = 1;
    response = Yes;
}
)
```

And my NSDictionary is not pulling the objectForKey. The jsonArray is displaying correctly. My code:

```
hostStr = [[hostStr stringByAppendingString:post] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *hostURL = [NSURL URLWithString:hostStr];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:hostURL];
self.jsonArray = [jsonString JSONValue]; 
[jsonString release];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);

NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [self.jsonArray objectForKey:@"ID"];

NSLog(infoDictionary);
```

Comment: JSON delimits properties with commas, not semicolons.

Comment: That shows the NSLog from the jsonArray...

Comment: It seems like this question needs to be re-tagged (at least php needs to be added; see my answer below).

Comment: Why in the bloody %$#@ are you using `objectForKey` on something named `jsonArray`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the case since you have completely invalid JSON (test it out at http://jsonlint.com/). Because you are missing the quotation marks in your JSON the elements won't match the id `ID`. All object names/keys need to be in quotation marks.

You're lucky that your framework interprets your invalid JSON (somehow) correctly so that you actually get an array or a dictionary. Because of this the result of `NSLog` will be correct.

Rewrite your JSON like this to get it working:

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "response": "YES"
}
```

(Also be sure that jsonArray is a `NSDictionary`)

Comment: I am connecting to a PHP page that uses print(json_encode($settings));I dont think I can change the way it outputs the json

Comment: Ah, probably the PHP function `print` prints the `( ... )`. Is it possible just to print out the raw JSON output?

Comment: Could you describe what types `$settings` include? Or what type `$settings` is? Or give us the link to the PHP page?

Comment: jsonArray is a NSDictionary, $settings looks like $settings[] = array("response" => "Yes", "ID" => $member['ID']); getting uncaught exception ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x47c0a50'

Comment: I just tested your code on my system. The problem is that you're using an array to store your encoded JSON (`$settings[]`). Can you try to print it as it's generated? The JSON that is being produced is valid on my system (PHP 5.3.6).

Comment: [{"response":"Yes","ID":"1"}] I just manually did it. objective c is parsing the JSON as it is above

Comment: I nslogged jsonString and it mimics the JSON i posted above

Comment: Retry it without the `[` and `]`. I think we should move this conversation into the chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6239/discussion-between-paul-engstler-and-savagenoob)